# JS what happens to my number

Tags: javascript, variables, numbers, leading-zero

In JavaScript when create a variable for example: 
x = 01234
It return the number 668.

Could somebody please explain to me why this happens?
Or how JavaScript handles numbers with a leading zero 0.

thanks in advance,
Michel

Comment: Leading zero denotes an octal. You should  `'use strict'`

Comment: _"You should `'use strict'`"_ That's overkill.

Comment: Try this : 

var yourdata = 01234;

function convertFromBaseToBase(str, fromBase, toBase){
 var num = parseInt(str, fromBase);
    return num.toString(toBase);
}

alert(convertFromBaseToBase(yourdata , 10, 8));

Comment: Dear Melpomene, Elclanrs and Cerbrus, Thank you!!